# Error getting login into Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to login into facebook using my android app. Actually i am following this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ but I am getting some error. here is my logcat output...

```
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1328)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:790)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:890)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:830)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-13 17:39:49.845: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is my code..

```
 Session.openActiveSession(this,true,new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(session.isOpened()){
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (user != null) {
                            System.out.println("HI facebook");
                          }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

      } );
```

ple help me.

Comment: Did you add the v4 support library?

Comment: yes add v4 support library. i am using android-4.0.3.

Comment: i add v4 support library manually as a jar file because it wouldn't find the library first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Android's SDK v4 support library instead of the Facebook's one, search for the support library inside Facebook's SDK and replace it with the one in your project.